# How can I implement a custom metrics "Negative Predictive Value" in python Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a code for calculating the Negative Predictive Value for the comparison of two arrays (y_pred and y_actual):

```
def npv(y_pred, y_actual):
    tn = 0
    fn = 0
    negative_value = 1

    for i in range(0,len(y_actual)):
        if(y_pred[i] == negative_value):
            if(y_pred[i] == y_actual[i]):
                tn += 1
            else:
                fn += 1

    result = tn / (tn + fn)
    return result
```

But I would like to implement it with tensors to use it as a custom metric in a deep learning recurrent neural network with Keras in python.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to write the metrics using simple Tensorflow. It's designed to work for binary classification tasks

```
def npv(y_actual, y_pred):

    negative_value = 1.

    if y_pred.shape[-1]==2: # last activation: softmax for binary classification
        y_actual = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_actual, -1), tf.float32) # get true class
        y_pred = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, -1), tf.float32) # get pred class

    else: # last activation: sigmoid for binary classification
        y_pred = tf.round(y_pred) # round probability 

    # if (y_pred == negative_value) and (y_pred == negative_value)
    tn = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_pred, negative_value), 
                                              tf.equal(y_pred, y_actual)), tf.float32))
    # if (y_pred == negative_value) and (y_pred != negative_value)
    fn = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_pred, negative_value), 
                                              tf.not_equal(y_pred, y_actual)), tf.float32))

    result = tn / ((tn + fn) + K.epsilon()) # add epsilon to avoid nan
    return result
```

and this is an example in a binary classification task

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,3))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, 100)

inp = Input((3))
x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(inp)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inp, x)
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=npv)
model.fit(X,y, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Feed it in as the `loss` parameter while calling `compile`:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=npv)
```

Keep in mind however that for a general custom loss function, the arguments need to be in the order `y_true, y_pred`, so you'll need to correct that in your function `npv()` first.